# Anonymous namespace in template implementation file

Tags: c++, namespaces, linkage, translation-unit

In a .cpp file, an anonymous namespace basically has file-wide linkage (after #includes) because the .cpp file will never be included by another file. But, the same pattern in a header file propagates that anonymous namespace to wherever it is included in. Is there a way to create a similar effect in a header file? I ask because template implementations must be in headers.

A simple example in a regular .h file would be this:

```
// object.h

namespace {
    using verbose::namespace::type;
}

...

struct object {  
    type value;
}
```

or similarly in some template implementation file. The type `type` would be in-scope of wherever this file is included.

Is there a way around this?

EDIT: I think I found a verbose but workable answer.

```
// object.h

struct Namespace {
     using verbose::namespace::type;

     Namespace() = delete;

     struct object {
         type value;
     };
};

using Namespace::object;
```

Comment: Just add `using type = verbose::namespace::type;` to the class?

Comment: I strongly prefer to not mix implementation style with the implementation itself. I could, but then object::type would be valid and that just seems messy. Even if I made it protected, then subclasses could see it. Making it private would disallow me to add a public using `type` to object in the future.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, and I wouldn't lose any ability. I'm trying to think of side-effects but I can't think of any (the point I edited into my comment above is invalid, cause the name would be taken anyways with the anon namespace).

Comment: It would be nice to separate it from the struct's definition though.

Comment: Since you don't want to pollute the global scope of anything that includes your file with that name you have to scope it somehow.  One option is to put all the code in the header in it's own namespace.  Another option is to scope the name to the class that is using it.

Comment: You can even do something like `namespace detail { using verbose::namespace::type; }` and then later use `detail::type`.

Comment: @NathanOliver What do you think of the added edit?

Comment: Is `using Namespace::object;` really needed?  Any source file could have that is they don't want to type `Namespace::object` all the time.

Comment: Wouldn't `using Namespace::object;` make it so they _don't_ have to do that? I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, it would mean they don't have to do that but it also means that anyone that includes your header can't use the name `object` in their own code.  If you don't use `using Namespace::object;` then you give the option of having that instead of forcing it on them.

Comment: True. In my head I knew there'd be a real namespace around this code (as I always do in projects); I should have added the surrounding namespace in the example. I agree with you. In this case I'd prefer a namespace instead of the `struct Namespace` because it's extendable in other files.

Comment: Oops.  I just realized you had `struct Namespace`.  My eyes lied to me and I though I saw `namespace Namespace`.

Comment: @NathanOliver no worries!

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick:

```
// object.h
{
    namespace {
        using verbose::namespace::type;
    }

    ...

    struct object {  
        type value;
    }
}
```

Namespaces should only be valid within the code block they're defined in.

Comment: Hmm. So the stuff inside the anonymous namespace wouldn't be visible, but I could still instantiate (and otherwise use) the object struct?

Comment: You can't just put a scope like that in the global space.